# Ratingbar component display more than specified number of stars in android

Tags: android, xml, rating

I am using rating bar component in my xml file and given specified  number of stars to be display; it still display more stars 
code of the rating bar in my xml is as below
can any one help me out in this matter ..?
i am using popup widget and inside popup relative layout and inside layout the below given 
rating bar
    enter code here

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504664/android-ratingbar-showing-more-than-5-stars

Answer (score 0):

Change your stepsize to one and have numStars to 2

```
 <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/foodratingBar"
            style="@drawable/ratingbarstyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ratingfoodtext"
            android:numStars="2"
            android:paddingLeft="45dip"
            android:paddingRight="28dip"
            android:rating="0.0"
            android:stepSize="1" />
```

Comment: thanks but neither setsize nor numstars is giving effect in rating bar in my app but all is working if i create another app

Comment: Are you using it under LinearLayout?

Comment: Did you tried by placing it outside somewhere of your popup widget or it's parent layout? I experienced this issue before. This happened because of layout. Don't know why.

Comment: what if i want to place it in layout and even if i am not placing in side layout or popup it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You got to set

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and

```
android:numStars=5
```

in your xml file for RatingsBar.