# Android RatingBar showing more than 5 stars

Tags: android

I want to show a rating bar via an alert dialog in my android app. The problem I am facing is that depending upon the width of the screen, the ratingbar shows more than 5 stars(upto 10) in landscape mode and the function setNumStars() has no effect. There are posts already dealing with this issue but they deal with a ratingbar whose laout is defined statically while I am creating it dynamically. How to solve this problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button launchButton;
//Rating dialog
 private AlertDialog.Builder rater;
 private RatingBar ratingBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    launchButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.ratingButton);
    launchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Here the alert dialog will be launched
            showRatingDialog();
        }
    });

      //Setting up rating dialog
        rater = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        rater.setTitle("This is the rating dialog");


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void showRatingDialog()
{
  ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingStars);
      rater.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", null);
      rater.setView(ratingBar);
      rater.show();

}
}
```

I have tried using static layout for the ratingbar but when I do this and try to display the ratingbar via an alert dialog, no stars are shown. Here is the layout file for rating bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingStars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set the step size as 0.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to set max value for your `RatingBar` Like Below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/active_bg" >

    <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1"
            android:isIndicator="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

create an xml file in your layout file and set this as the content

Change your `showDialog` function like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.***your_xml_name***));
editor.setView(layout);
editor.show();
```

Comment: These changes have no effect.

Comment: When I declared in xml file and set the content its working fine, if you want I can post the code

Comment: Yes, if its no problem for you

Comment: I am trying to show the ratingbar via an alert dialog and if I use a static layout as you have mentioned, no ratingbar shows up on alert dialog.Please see the showRatingDialog function

Comment: It works!But the correct code is:   rater.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_rarting_layout_id, null)); Please edit your answer and I will mark it, Thank you!

Comment: see the edited answer sorry, I thought you will figure it out nice catch :)

Comment: RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(context);

  ratingBar.setNumStars(5);  not working

Comment: This answer has no proper explanation. all need to be done is set `numStars` and width to `wrap_content` of ratingbar

Answer (score 24):

set the `android:numStars="5"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 19):

setting the width of the RatingBar to "wrap content" solves the whole issue.
According to the documentation:

> Sets the number of stars to show. In order for these to be shown
>   properly, it is recommended the layout width of this widget be wrap
>   content.

Answer (score 3):

keep parent of rating bar as linear layout and keep nothing else in that linear layout, that worked for me

[This](http://lees2bytes.blogspot.in/2014/03/ratingbar-madness-and-solution.html)
blog shows the clear picture of solution

Comment: Works perfectly, I don't know why this has no upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

If your RatingBar is in an AlertDialog, stick in inside of a LinearLayout and use setView on the LinearLayout. Then you can set its width to WRAP_CONTENT.